# How is oAuth used?

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-sheets-api

On my Raspberry Pi 2 I'm reading the following:
Temperature, humidity and pressure.
Earlier, I  maded a node.js server, which I could access via a browser both locally and globally.
Now I want to be able to write from the node.js program directly to the Google sheet,  by adding rows of the 3 values.
There are several npm packages that can do this.
And I know you need oAuth certification for this: But I'm having some difficulty translating this into a practical example.
I have tried to create a certificate and receive a client_secret file.
But then what?
Can anyone refer to a practical example (node.js)?

(I can easily handle reading the sensors and the other node.js programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how Sheets API works with NodeJS, you should check the [NodeJS Sheets API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs). It shows the OAuth process, how setup is done up to making calls to the Sheets API.

Comment: A fine article. Thanks.
The program code also seems to work. 
But: 
I get the following error when I enter the acces token:
Error while trying to retrieve access token { 
Error: invalid_grant  .. ..  . 
 at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20) code: 400 }

Comment: The error has been found.
In the example, I had to change:  'Class Data!A2:E', to 'A2:E', .
Now I can read the contents of a Google Sheet file.
Then I just need to be able to write too ...